# how to set color of RecyclerView.ViewHolder in BroadcastReceiver.onReceive?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, kotlin

i am creating an app that scans for and pairs to Bluetooth devices. i am displaying the devices in a RecyclerView and indicating bond state by coloring the ViewHolder for that device. my problem is that the color of the ViewHolder is only changed after scanning for devices again and i want it to immediately update the color on pair or unpair. i am attempting to do this through use of a broadcast receiver but i am unable to get a reference to the correct ViewHolder. how can i achieve this? i am including my code below for my RecyclerView.Adapter and my BluetoothUtils file containing the broadcast receiver. thanks in advance. my adapter:

```
class DeviceAdapter(val mContext : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder>() {

companion object {
    val TAG = "Device Adapter"

    fun DeviceHolder.setColor(bonded: Boolean):Unit{
        val background = if (bonded)Color.CYAN else Color.TRANSPARENT
        this.itemView.setBackgroundColor(background)
    }

}

val mDevices = ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()

fun updateItems(list: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>) {
    mDevices.clear()
    mDevices.addAll(list)
    Log.d(TAG, "updating items : $mDevices")
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun ViewGroup.inflate(@LayoutRes res: Int, attachToRoot: Boolean = false): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(res, this, attachToRoot)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DeviceHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called!")
    holder.bindItems(mDevices.get(position))
    if (mDevices.get(position).bondState==BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(CYAN)
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder called!")
    val v = parent!!.inflate(R.layout.device_item, false)
    return DeviceHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mDevices.size
}

inner class DeviceHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView) as TextView
    val addrView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressView) as TextView
    var dialog: AlertDialog? = null;

    fun bindItems(btDevice: BluetoothDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "holder created!")
        nameView.text = btDevice.name ?: "Unknown"
        addrView.text = btDevice.address
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(it.context)
                    .setTitle("Options")
                    .setView(R.layout.options_dialog_layout)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which -> })
                    .create()
            dialog!!.show()
            val ops = listOf(
                    dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.statOp),
                    dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.pairOp),
                    dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.connectOp),
                    dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.sendOp),
                    dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.unPairOp)
            )
            ops.forEach { it.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(it.context, it.id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                when(it.id){
                    R.id.statOp -> {}
                    R.id.connectOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connectOp reached")
                        BluetoothReflection.connectDevice(btDevice)
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }// BluetoothUtils.connect(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), btDevice)
                    R.id.pairOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "pairOp reached")
                        BluetoothUtils.startPair(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), btDevice)
                        if (btDevice.bondState==BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                            this@DeviceHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(CYAN) //doesn't work
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "start pair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }//
                    R.id.unPairOp -> {//no executable code found here
                        Log.d(TAG, "unPairOp reached")
                        BluetoothUtils.unPair(btDevice)
                        if (btDevice.bondState==BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE){
                            this@DeviceHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) //doesn't work
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "unpair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
                    R.id.sendOp -> {}
                }
            } }
        }

    }
}
}
```

and my BluetoothUtils:

```
class BluetoothUtils {

companion object {

    var listener: ListenThread? = null

    val _UUID = UUID.fromString("a0e7e4c7-0e4e-43b7-9d18-659192512164")
    val TAG = "BluetoothUtils"

    val receiver = MainBTStatusReceiver()

    fun initPairingServer(adapter: BluetoothAdapter){
        var mmServerSocket: BluetoothServerSocket?
        try {
            var tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(TAG, _UUID)
            mmServerSocket = tmp
            listener = ListenThread(mmServerSocket)
            listener!!.start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing Bluetooth", ioe)
        }
    }

    fun cancelListener() = listener!!.cancel()

    fun connect(adapter: BluetoothAdapter, device: BluetoothDevice){
        var btSocket: BluetoothSocket?

        try {
            adapter.cancelDiscovery()
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID)
            PairingThread(btSocket).start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        }
    }

    fun startPair(adapter: BluetoothAdapter, device: BluetoothDevice): Unit{
        adapter.cancelDiscovery()
        Log.d(TAG, device.bondState.toString())
        device.createBond()
    }

    fun unPair(device: BluetoothDevice): Any = device::class.java.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(device)

}
}

class ListenThread(val btServSock: BluetoothServerSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "ListenThread"
}

var btSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

override fun run() {
    super.run()
    while (true){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "listening . . . ")
            btSocket = btServSock.accept()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", ioe) // SHOULD HANDLE FAILURE OF LISTENER INSTANTIATION
            break
        }

        //manage connection here
        //with either BluetoothUtils function
        //or BluetoothSocket extension
    }
}

fun cancel() = btServSock.close()
}

class PairingThread(val btSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "Pairing Thread"
}

override fun run() {
    super.run()

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "attempting to connect")
        btSocket.connect()
    }catch (ioe: IOException){
        Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        btSocket.close()
    }
}
}


class MainBTStatusReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver(){

val TAG = "MainBTStatusReceiver"
var mAdapter: DeviceAdapter? = null

fun setAdapter(adapter: DeviceAdapter){
    mAdapter = adapter
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
    val action = intent.action
    val devExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE) as BluetoothDevice
    when(action){
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED -> {
            val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            when(device.bondState){
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "BONDED")
                }
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING -> {Log.d(TAG, "BONDING")}
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE -> {Log.d(TAG, "NONE")}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `boolean` or `int` to `BluetoothDevice` model for managing view.

For example,

BluetoothDevice: added `isOn` state. (Sorry, it's Java)

```
class BluetoothDevice {
    boolean isOn;

    public boolean isOn() {
        return isOn;
    }

    public void setOn(boolean isOn) {
        this.isOn = isOn;
    }
}
```

DeviceHolder: changed color of view

```
fun bindItems(btDevice: BluetoothDevice) {
   stateView.textColor = btDevice.isOn() ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN
}
```

DeviceAdapter: added `getItems`

```
fun getItems() {
   return mDevices
}
```

If you want to change `isOn` state, change model and notify it.

```
adapter.getItems().get(i).setOn(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the above answer as well but the way that i got this done was to pass the BroadcastReceiver into the DeviceAdapter :

```
class DeviceAdapter(val mContext:Context, val mReceiver:MainBTStatusReceiver) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder>()
```

and then made a ViewHolder a member of the BroadcastReceiver and a setter function for the ViewHolder named setFocus. before calling any functions from the BluetoothUtils class i called the setFocus function and then the broadcast receiver modifies the color of the view that focus is currently set too. I do have some concern that this might not be  reliable as the most accurate method to modify the correct ViewHolder every time. if you see any problem with this please comment to let me know.

my updated BroadcastReceiver:

```
class MainBTStatusReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {

val TAG = "MainBTStatusReceiver"
var holder: DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder? = null

fun setFocus(holder: DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder) {
    this.holder = holder
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
    val action = intent.action
    when (action) {
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED -> {
            val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            when (device.bondState) {
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED -> {
                    holder!!.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)
                    Log.d(TAG, "BONDED")
                }
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BONDING")
                }
                BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE -> {
                    holder!!.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    Log.d(TAG, "NONE")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the two statements in my when expression that call setFocus():

```
              R.id.pairOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "pairOp reached")
                        mReceiver.setFocus(this@DeviceHolder)
                        BluetoothUtils.startPair(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), btDevice)
                        Log.d(TAG, "start pair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
                    R.id.unPairOp -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "unPairOp reached")
                        mReceiver.setFocus(this@DeviceHolder)
                        BluetoothUtils.unPair(btDevice)
                        Log.d(TAG, "unpair complete")
                        dialog!!.dismiss()
                    }
```